# Add elements between nodes Ordered LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, boolean, addition

I queried the search engine on this site, but I did not see anything that matched what I am looking for, so I hope this question has not already been answered elsewhere.  I am trying to perfect my add method for an ordered LinkedList.  The rest of the program runs fine, and while the list prints out as specified in the test harness, I want the names to be sorted.

My output is this after several calls to add and remove from the harness:

```
Sue, Bill, Michael, Someguy, Michael, Carl, Steve, Carl, Sue
Sue, Bill, Someguy, Michael, Steve, Carl, Sue
Sue, Bill, Someguy, Michael, Steve, Carl, Sue, Sue, Bill
```

What I want is this:
Sue, Sue, Bill, Michael, Michael, Carl, Carl, Steve, etc...

My add method:

```
 public boolean add(Comparable obj)
{
    OrderedListNode newNode = new OrderedListNode(obj, null, null);
    if( tail == null) {
    tail = newNode;
    head = tail;
    modCount++;
    return true;

    }
    if(((Comparable)(head.theItem)).equals(obj)){
        tail.previous = newNode;
        modCount++;
        return true;
    }else{


    tail.previous.next = newNode;
    newNode.previous = tail.previous;
    newNode.next = tail;
    tail.previous = newNode;
    modCount++;
    return true;
    }
}
```

Entire Code, since it was asked for:

```
package dataStructures;


public class OrderedLinkedList
{

/**************************************************************************
 * Constants
 *************************************************************************/

/** return value for unsuccessful searches */
private static final OrderedListNode NOT_FOUND = null;


/**************************************************************************
 * Attributes
 *************************************************************************/

/** current number of items in list */
private int theSize;

/** reference to list header node */
private OrderedListNode head;

/** reference to list tail node */
private OrderedListNode tail;

/** current number of modifications to list */
private int modCount;


/**************************************************************************
 * Constructors
 *************************************************************************/


/**
 *  Create an instance of OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 */
public OrderedLinkedList()
{
    // empty this OrderedLinkedList
    clear();
}


/**************************************************************************
 * Methods
 *************************************************************************/


/*
 *  Add the specified item to this OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 *  @param  obj     the item to be added
 */
public boolean add(Comparable obj)
{
    OrderedListNode newNode = new OrderedListNode(obj, null, null);
    if( tail == null) {
    tail = newNode;
    head = tail;
    modCount++;
    return true;

    }
    if(((Comparable)(head.theItem)).compareTo(obj) > 0){
        ////////////////////////////////////////
        //here is where my problem lies, I believe
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        modCount++;
        return true;
    }else{


    tail.previous.next = newNode;
    newNode.previous = tail.previous;
    newNode.next = tail;
    tail.previous = newNode;
    modCount++;
    return true;
    }
}

/*
 *  Remove the first occurrence of the specified item from this OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 *  @param  obj     the item to be removed
 */
public boolean remove(Comparable obj)
{
    if(head == null) return false;
    if(((Comparable)(head.theItem)).compareTo(obj) == 0) {
    if(head == tail) {
        head = tail = null;
        return true;
    }
    head = head.next;
    return true;
    }

    if(head == tail)return false;
    OrderedListNode ref = head;
    while( ref.next != tail) {
        if(((Comparable)(ref.next.theItem)).compareTo(obj) == 0) {
            ref.next = ref.next.next;
            return true;
        }
        ref = ref.next;
    }
    if(((Comparable)(tail.theItem)).compareTo(obj) == 0 ) {
        tail = ref;
        tail.next = null;
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}


/**
 *  Empty this OrderedLinkedList.
 */
public void clear()
{
    // reset header node
    head = new OrderedListNode("HEAD", null, null);

    // reset tail node
    tail = new OrderedListNode("TAIL", head, null);

    // header references tail in an empty LinkedList
    head.next = tail;

    // reset size to 0
    theSize = 0;

    // emptying list counts as a modification
    modCount++;
}


/**
 *  Return true if this OrderedLinkedList contains 0 items.
 */
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return theSize == 0;
}


/**
 *  Return the number of items in this OrderedLinkedList.
 */
public int size()
{
    return theSize;
}


/*  
 *  Return a String representation of this OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 *  (non-Javadoc)
 *  @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";

    OrderedListNode currentNode = head.next;

    while (currentNode != tail)
    {
        s += currentNode.theItem.toString();

        if (currentNode.next != tail)
        {
            s += ", ";
        }

        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    return s;
}

private static class OrderedListNode<Comparable> {

    Comparable theItem;
    OrderedListNode<Comparable> next;
    OrderedListNode<Comparable> previous;

    public OrderedListNode(Comparable theItem, OrderedListNode<Comparable> previous, OrderedListNode<Comparable> next) {
        this.theItem = theItem;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It's impossible to understand looking just at one method. Please add enough code to see how your output is formed. It's also not clear what your "*I want the names to be sorted*" actually means.

Comment: Not sure if this helps

Answer (score 0):

This line is definitely wrong

```
if(((Comparable)(head.theItem)).equals(obj)) {
```

you should use Comparable.compareTo, besides you should always start from head and go until you find an element greater or equal to obj and insert obj before it, something like this

```
public boolean add(Comparable obj) {
    modCount++;
    if (head == null) {
        head = new OrderedListNode(obj, null, null);
        return true;
    }
    for (OrderedListNode current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
        if (((Comparable) (current.theItem)).compareTo(obj) >= 0) {
            current.prev = new OrderedListNode(obj, current.prev, current);
            return true;
        }
    }
    tail.next = new OrderedListNode(obj, tail, null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That prints out just the head, but I'll play around with it.  Thanks

Comment: So, I want to take the newNode, and assign it to the next node after the object being compare to, if they are the same, right?  Am I looking at it the right way?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is sort the items as they are added, so shouldn't I be comparing them as equal?  Why use the > 0 operator? I ask because I simply don't know, not because I am arguing with you.

Comment: All objects inherit equals from `Object`, which you can override. If you are specifically using the `Comparable` interface, you should use the methods that it provides (`compareTo`).

Comment: I think you should always start from head and go until you find an element which is greater or equal and insert before it

Comment: That said, this looks like a school assignment/learning question. Generics would throw you into a world of hurt. Don't worry about that. Your data item should probably be `Comparable` though, instead of requiring a cast that you don't check for (if I stored `Person` instances as `theItem` and didn't implement `Comparable`, your program would crash.

Comment: Certainly is a school assignment...but only for self enrichment.  I have my MS, just looking to learn how to code to enhance my engineering background.  Regardless, I see why I need to compareTo instead of equals, thanks.  Now, what I'm thinking is this is not correct:

Comment: You are right about the person instances, it would crash without Comparable being implemented.  Tried it.